# How to exclude duplicated values from single xml node using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, duplicates

I have to exclude duplicated values from a single node using XSLT

ex.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<base>
<string>test1,test2,test3,test1,test4,test2,test5,</string>
</base>
```

The result should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<base>
string>test1,test2,test3,test4,test5,</string>
</base>
```

Could anyone help me with this please ?

Comment: What version of XSLT/XSLT engine?

Comment: Questions should use one of the xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, or xslt-3.0 tags as appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to do this in XSLT 1.0, You should be able to do something like this [xsl: how to split strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845660/xsl-how-to-split-strings), and maybe using a `document()` function if it's supported by your processor to load the results of that into a document and then maybe use an `xsl:key` to get the distinct results.  It's pretty convoluted though. Here is another method that avoids some of that convolution using pure XSLT 1.0: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34944992/3016153.

My preference would still be for some kind of extension for this; if you're doing this using MSXML, you could do something like the following (I'd probably prefer C# here, but JavaScript is probably more portable if you're not using MSXML):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:user="http://mycompany.com/mynamespace">
  <xsl:template match="/base/string">
    <xsl:value-of select="user:distinctSplit(string(.))" />
  </xsl:template>
  <msxsl:script language="JScript" implements-prefix="user">

   function distinctSplit(str) {
      var u = {}, a = [];
      var splt = str.split(',');
      for(var i = 0;i &lt; splt.length;i++) {
        if (u.hasOwnProperty(splt[i])) {
          continue;
        }
        a.push(splt[i]);
        u[splt[i]] = 1;
      }

      return a.join(',');
   }
 </msxsl:script>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you're not using MSXML, you might be able to get a tokenize extension or use your processor's method of embedding JavaScript (and your processor might even support the `.filter()` function for arrays, which could make this code simpler - testing locally with MSXML didn't support `filter()` for me).

If you're using XSLT 2.0, you could use `tokenize` and `distinct-values`, something like this should work:

```
<xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(tokenize(/base/string, ','))" separator=",">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ',')" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

but you might have to play with it a little as it may add extra `,` literals that you don't want at the end.

Comment: For XSLT 2.0 it is working perfectly fine , thank You ! Is it also possible to somehow do it in XSLT 1.0 ?

Comment: The first part of my answer is for XSLT 1.0 - but there's no easy/straightforward way to do it without extensions.  I started playing with it and while I'm sure it's somehow possible I don't think it'd be pretty.  If you found the answer helpful, consider upvoting it and marking it as accepted for future users.

Comment: The XSLT 2.0 suggestion can be shortened to `<xsl:value-of select="distinct-values(tokenize(/base/string, ','))" separator=","/>`, without needing to worry about extra commas at the end.

Comment: @PiotrP For an XSLT 1.0 solution, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34944992/3016153

Comment: @DanField "*there's no easy/straightforward way to do it without extensions.*" Ahem.

Comment: Edited again @michael.hor257k - that's definitely better than the path I was attempting, but IMO it's still not as straight forward as using an extension...